# gcc, enum is not packed as expected

Tags: c, gcc

The size of enum is not packed, why is that?

```
typedef enum{
    STATE_IDLE = 0,
    STATE_RUN,
}State_t;

#pragma pack(1)
struct {
    char c;             //1
    State_t State;      // should be 1 but is 4
    uint32_t Time;      //4
    sCB_t CB;           //4

}App;
#pragma pack()

int main()
{
    printf("Size bytes: %u\n", sizeof(App));
    return 0;
}
```

The above will output

```
Size bytes: 13
```

I use CodeBlocks 16.01 with gcc on x86

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin>mingw32-gcc.exe --version
mingw32-gcc.exe (tdm-1) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Also `__attribute__((packed))` is not working, after some dig I found `#pragma` equivalent.

Comment: Packing prevents alignment padding from being added. I wouldn't expect it to turn an enum into a bitfield.

Comment: Worse: there is no guarantee an `enum` is an `int`. See the standard. In case you intend to serialise this `struct`: **just don't**. Use proper serialisation to a machine-independent data-format.

Answer (score 12):

`#pragma pack` does not affect sizes of data types. It's purpose is to remove padding in structures.

With GCC on x86 enums have size of 4 or even 8 bytes  some values do not fit in 4 bytes. If you need to make them shorter, there are 2 ways, both are non-standard:

- Use `-fshort-enums` flag - dangerous, as this changes ABI of all enums. Basically you should never use this.
- Use  `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` when declaring enum to achieve the same effect only for that type.

You can declare it like this:

```
typedef enum __attribute__((packed)) {
    STATE_IDLE = 0,
    STATE_RUN,
} State_t;
```

Note: you mentioned `__attribute__((packed))` did not work for you, but I think you were using it incorrectly. I was able to get the size of 10 bytes for your structure.

Comment: I avoided to use -fshort-enums, I have some SDK that may not like it. For tests, I use CodeBlocks on x86 so it make sens to me only (It will compiled later for Xtensa core). The problem is that in Code Blocks the __attribute__ ((__packed__)) is not working so if you say it should, probably it's my environment.

Comment: @orfruit I have just checked it on Windows with MinGW and it works for me - `sizeof(State_t)` is 1. The same worked on Linux. Unless your code is different from what you have posted?

Comment: updated to CodeBlocks 17 (latest), delete all MinGW and now works (was MinGW compiler problem). I accepted your answer because confirmed that works close to my environment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using gcc on my system (x64_64 Ubuntu), the type `State_t` has a size of 4 bytes.

That's determined when `State_t` is defined. Applying `#pragma pack(1)` to a structure type you define later has no effect on `State_t`.

(The size of an enumerated type is implementation-defined. gcc's documentation should tell you how that's done.)

Comment: Hmm.. I see. So State_t is determined before attribute... ok, so how can I enforce to be uint8_t?

Comment: You can pack the enums - locally by the correct use of the attribute, or globally by -fshort-enums parameter. BTW it does not have too much sense on the x86 systems

Answer (score 0):

I found a more complete answer, In case anyone needs.

For correct packing, bigger types must be positioned first (ie. to lower memory address), see this picture.

Since I've do some tests for further embedded (that will be recompiled) I will not investigate more, this is at least on my machine, Win 7 Ultimate 64 bit, i5-4200 CPU.

[image]

Comment: You can check [this](https://ideone.com/qomN6q). Both cases give size of 5 bytes. Member field order is relevant to avoid padding in structures, but if you are using `__attribute__((packed))`, then padding is removed anyway. So the order of fields has no effect on the size of the structure. Unless GCC behaves somewhat different on Windows.

Comment: @Ivan, I put real image. On my machine you can see the it isn't. I suspect it's about aligning or something. Anyhow, if there was align problem, there should be a violation anyhow and is not. If I read right, modern CPUs solve this in HW but probably is gcc....

Comment: You are using `__attribute__((packed))` which disables effect of alignment on member field offsets - that is the whole point of that attribute. So if you get what you get, there is something really wrong with your compiler. You said upgrading MinGW helped. What exactly did it change? SIze of enum?

Comment: Yes, I was used some old CodeBlocks 16 or whatever with C:\MinGW. Now I uninstalled, deleted that MinGW, download latest CB 17 and use it's MinGW (package with MinGW included). WIth old one, size of enum was always 4, now is 1 as it supposed to (packed). But struct isn't packed unless my post above.You can download and try.

Answer (score 0):

it will works even in old gcc

```
#if defined(__MINGW32__)
#   define __is_packed       __attribute__((__gcc_struct__, __packed__, __aligned__(1)))
#else
#   define __is_packed       __attribute__((__packed__, __aligned__(1)))
#endif
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.